# How to add an integer to a date field in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Have a WHERE clause in my SQL query in Snowflake where I would like to filter by adding an integer to a date field:

`AND CAST(DATETIME AS DATE) >= '2022-10-26' + 30`

SNK returns me this error: **invalid type [TO_DATE((2022 - 10) - 26)] for parameter 'TO_DATE'**

Anyone know how to overturn this error?

Comment: You cannot add 30 to a date. You can add 30 days or 30 years, whatever. For this reason you must add an interval where you specify the unit as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DATEADD()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html) function to add days:

```sql
CAST(DATETIME AS DATE) >= DATEADD(day, 30, '2022-10-26')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `INTERVAL` arithmetic:

```
CAST(DATETIME AS DATE) >= '2022-10-26'::DATE + INTERVAL '30 DAYS'
```

Answer (score 0):

the base problem `'2022-10-26' + 30` is that a `string` and `number` do not implicitly compare to a `date`

So there are a couple of ways to do the cast:

```
select
    column1 as datetime
    ,to_date(datetime, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as d1
    ,try_to_date(datetime, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as d2
    ,datetime::date as d3
    ,cast(datetime as date) as d4
    --,d1 + 30 as add1
   -- ,dateadd(day, 30, '2022-10-26') as add2
    --,d1 + interval '30 days'
from values
    ('2023-02-10'),
    ('2022-10-26');
```

| DATETIME | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-10 | 2023-02-10 | 2023-02-10 | 2023-02-10 | 2023-02-10 |
| 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-26 |

and the second half is addition

```
select
    column1 as datetime
    ,to_date(datetime, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as d1
    ,d1 + 30 as add1
    ,dateadd(day, 30, '2022-10-26') as add2
    ,d1 + interval '30 days' as add3
from values
    ('2023-02-10'),
    ('2022-10-26')
```

| DATETIME | D1 | ADD1 | ADD2 | ADD3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-10 | 2023-02-10 | 2023-03-12 | 2022-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2023-03-12 |
| 2022-10-26 | 2022-10-26 | 2022-11-25 | 2022-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2022-11-25 |

this shows that DATEADD can handle being given a string (constant of dynamic) and the compiler will correctly cast the string to DATE, but then the DATEADD givens you a TIMESTAMP back. But the two inline addition methods require the date side of the addition to already be a date, thus it needs casting in one fashion or another.